# 0.3 MP front facing camera can not read QR code by using zxing

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I have 9.7 inc polypad tablet (0.3 mp), zxing barcode reader cannot scan qr code but itcan scan  by using samsung 10.1 tablet .

Have you experienced a problem like this ?

i am working with [ZXing-2.2 and barcodescanner 4.3.2](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list)

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suffer from the same issue with a 7 inch Nexus 7 tablet with ZBar library. I guess it is not a library issue but it due to the following fact:

- Not a good enough resolution
- No autofocus
- The use of QR codes which are a little big harder to decode than standart barcodes

Comment: i think so that it is not an zxing library problem. thanks Damien